# Dynamic values in list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x

I have list something like below

```py
players_info= [
    {'Player': 'Player1', 'team': 'Hockey', 'Country': 'India'},
    {'Player': 'Player2', 'team': 'Cricket', 'Country': 'India'}
]
```

New players information should be added to players information list with country default set to India

```py
new_players_info = {"Player3": "Badminton", "Player4": "Tennis"}
```

Output should be like below

```py
players_info= [
    {'Player': 'Player1', 'team': 'Hockey', 'Country': 'India'},
    {'Player': 'Player2', 'team': 'Cricket', 'Country': 'India'},
    {'Player': 'Player3', 'team': 'Badminton', 'Country': 'India'},
    {'Player': 'Player4', 'team': 'Tennis', 'Country': 'India'},
]
```

Comment: You could pack your append logic into a function with default parameters. Also, a dictionary is probably not the best choice for your player record. You can take a look at  ``collections.namedtuple`` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
for player, team in new_players_info.items():
    info = {'Player': player, 'team': team, 'Country': 'India'},
    players_info.append(info)
```